# Can't write on recently created EXT4 partition

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, ext4, external-hdd

On a new external hard drive (Intenso 05-1204-18A), I made (with GParted) two partitions :

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204883968 bytes, 1953525164 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfa00a60d

Device     Boot    Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1           2048   50794495   50792448  24.2G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sdc2       50794496 1953523711 1902729216 907.3G 83 Linux
```

(I am using Linux 3.19.3-3-ARCH GNU/Linux)

When I mount the first (by using file manager, but it works with terminal too), I can see :

```
drwxr-x---+ 3 felicien felicien    60 Apr 16 16:31 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root        60 Apr 16 15:58 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 felicien felicien 16384 Jan  1  1970 INTENSO WIN
```

I can mkdir and everything in this directory. When I mount the second :

```
drwxr-x---+ 4 felicien felicien    80 Apr 16 16:32 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root        60 Apr 16 15:58 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 felicien felicien 16384 Jan  1  1970 INTENSO WIN
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root      4096 Apr 16 16:02 Intenso Linux
```

I have to chown the directory to be able to write into it. Why have I permissions with FAT32 and not EXT4 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fat32 filesystem has no notion of ownership or permissions. The man page for `mount` lists these options that help make it look closer to what Unix users expect:

> ```
> uid=value and gid=value
>       Set the owner and group of all files.  (Default: the uid and gid
>       of the current process.)
>
> umask=value
>       Set the umask (the bitmask  of  the  permissions  that  are  not
>       present).  The default is the umask of the current process.
> ```

So when you mounted it, it was mounted with your userid, groupid, and umask (which I'm guessing is `022`). All files and directories will be owned by you, and will have permissions `rwxr-xr-x`.

ext4, on the other hand, is a classic Unix filesystem that stores userid, groupid, and permissions information. If you create a directory while running as root, it will be owned by root, until you use `chown` to change it. You can change the *group* or *other* permissions, using `chmod`, to make an object be writable by multiple users.

Comment: Thank you ! I have chmod 777 the directory, there is an ugly green color on my terminal but I can write into it :)